# URLs with trailing questionmark (?)

Tags: redirects, url, canonical-url

I understand that URLs with or without trailing slash are considered two different resources and therefore we should use redirects to tell Google which one is the canonical one.

But what about trailing `?` (and nothing else behind, so basically empty GET parameters). Do I need to care about them and should I redirect them to the same URL without a trailing `?`?

Comment: It's still a different URL and theoretically different content _could_ be served based on the URL. The same principle applies as in this other question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87318/is-the-order-of-querystring-parameters-a-factor-in-duplicate-content-in-google/87322#87322

Comment: Make sure you set the correct URL in your canonical tag so that search engines know which to prefer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WordPress as CMS you can install Yoast SEO and in that you can set permalink to overcome this issue.

If you are using PHP you will need code to set permalink.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can/should do:

## 1. Search Console Settings

In Google Search Console, help Google understand how it should [treat different get parameters](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550?hl=en).  More often than not Google will get this right, but there's no harm in providing additional information, so long as it is accurate.

## 2. Canonicals

If the get variable is for tracking purposes and or doesn't affect the content on the page, set a canonical to the version of the page you would like Google to serve.  If the content is paginated and the get parameter specifies page number or limit, set the canonical to point to the "All" page.  If an all page doesn't exist, you can specify previous and or next as well as a canonical, but be sure to not set the canonical to just the first page of results.  More on this can be found [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en).